# Issues of using sort and comm

Tags: linux, shell, sort, comm

I was trying to find the intersection of two plain data files, and found from a previous post that it can be done through

```
comm -12 <(sort test1.list) < (sort test2.list)
```

It seems to me that `sort test1.list` aims to sort test1.list in order. In order to understand how `sort` works, I tried `sort` against the following file, test1.list as `sort test1.list > test2.list`

```
100
-200
300
2
92
15
340
```

However, it turns out that test2.list is

```
100
15
2
-200
300
340
92
```

This re-ordered list make me quite confused about how this sort works, and how does sort and comm work together.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Per the `comm` manual, "Before `comm' can be used, the input files must be sorted using the collating sequence specified by the `LC_COLLATE' locale."

And the `sort` manual: "Unless otherwise specified, all comparisons use the character collating sequence specified by the `LC_COLLATE' locale.

Therefore, and a quick test confirms, the `LC_COLLATE` order `comm` expects is provided by the `sort`'s default order, dictionary sort.

`sort` can sort files in a variety of manners:

- `-d`: Dictionary order - ignores anything but whitespace and alphanumerics.
- `-g`: General numeric - alpha, then negative numbers, then positive.
- `-h`: Human-readable - negative, alpha, positive. `n < nk = nK < nM < nG`
- `-n`: Numeric - negative, alpha, positive. `k`,`M`,`G`, etc. are not special.
- `-V`: Version - positive, caps, lower, negative. `1 < 1.2 < 1.10`
- `-f`: Case-insensitive.
- `-R`: Random - shuffle the input.
- `-r`: Reverse - usually used with one of `dghnV`

There are other options, of course, but these are the ones you're likely to see or need.

Your test shows that the default sort order is probably `-d`, dictionary order.

```
  d   |   g   |   h   |   n   |   V 
------+-------+-------+-------+-------
  1   |  a    | -1G   | -10   |  1
 -1   |  A    | -1k   | -5    |  1G
  10  |  z    | -10   | -1    |  1g
 -10  |  Z    | -5    | -1g   |  1k
  1.10| -10   | -1    | -1G   |  1.2
  1.2 | -5    | -1g   | -1k   |  1.10
  1g  | -1    |  a    |  a    |  5
  1G  | -1g   |  A    |  A    |  10
 -1g  | -1G   |  z    |  z    |  A
 -1G  | -1k   |  Z    |  Z    |  Z
  1k  |  1    |  1    |  1    |  a
 -1k  |  1g   |  1g   |  1g   |  z
  5   |  1G   |  1.10 |  1G   | -1
 -5   |  1k   |  1.2  |  1k   | -1G
  a   |  1.10 |  5    |  1.10 | -1g
  A   |  1.2  |  10   |  1.2  | -1k
  z   |  5    |  1k   |  5    | -5
  Z   |  10   |  1G   |  10   | -10
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to flesh out Kevin's comprehensive and illustrative answer: if you run `comm` with the case-insensitive flag, `comm -i`, you must also sort case-insensitively, e.g., `sort -f`.

Full example:

```
comm -i <(sort -i test1.list) <(sort -i test2.list)
```

Otherwise, the native `sort` (no flags) works.

Comment: `comm -i` is only available on BSD. [POSIX comm](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html) does not specify `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the sorting using `sort -n filename` for sorting and use the `comm` command.

Comment: I tried comm -12 <(sort test1.list)  <(sort test2.list) and  comm -12 <(sort -n test1.list)  <(sort test2.list)  looks like the results are the same. Does that mean that the -n option and -d option of sort do not affect the result of comm.