# Randomly draw a certain number of lines from a data file

Tags: linux, shell, text-processing

I have a data list, like

```
12345
23456
67891
-20000
200
600
20
...
```

Assume the size of this data set (i.e. lines of file) is `N`. I want to randomly draw `m` lines from this data file. Therefore, the output should be two files, one is the file including these `m` lines of data, and the other one includes `N-m` lines of data.

Is there a way to do that using a Linux command?

Comment: Are you concerned about the sequence of lines? eg. Do you want to maintain the source order, or do you want that sequence to be itself random as well as the choice of lines being random?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This might not be the most efficient way but it works:

```
shuf <file> > tmp
head -n $m tmp > out1
tail -n +$(( m + 1 )) tmp > out2
```

With `$m` containing the number of lines.

Comment: @userunknown, `sort -R` takes care of the randomness. Not sure if you downvoted the answer for that, but look it up in the manpage first.

Comment: Note that `sort -R` doesn't exactly sort its input randomly: it groups identical lines. So if the input is e.g. `foo`, `foo`, `bar`, `bar` and m=2, then one file will contain both `foo`s and the other will contain both `bar`s. GNU coreutils also has `shuf`, which randomizes the input lines. Also, [you don't need a temporary file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29709/randomly-draw-a-certain-number-of-lines-from-a-data-file/29747#29747).

Comment: why not `shuf <file> |head -n $m`?

Comment: @emanuele: Because we need both the head and the tail in two separate files.

Answer (score 5):

This bash/awk script chooses lines at random, and maintains the original sequence in both output files.

```
awk -v m=4 -v N=$(wc -l <file) -v out1=/tmp/out1 -v out2=/tmp/out2 \
 'BEGIN{ srand()
         do{ lnb = 1 + int(rand()*N)
             if ( !(lnb in R) ) {
                 R[lnb] = 1
                 ct++ }
         } while (ct<m)
  } { if (R[NR]==1) print > out1 
      else          print > out2       
  }' file
cat /tmp/out1
echo ========
cat /tmp/out2
```

Output, based ont the data in the question.

```
12345
23456
200
600
========
67891
-20000
20
```

Answer (score 5):

As with all things Unix, There's a Utility for That<sup>TM</sup>.

Program of the day: `split`
`split` will split a file in many different ways, `-b` bytes, `-l` lines, `-n` number of output files.  We will be using the `-l` option.  Since you want to pick random lines and not just the first `m`, we'll `sort` the file randomly first. If you want to read about `sort`, refer to my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29685/11750).

Now, the actual code. It's quite simple, really:

```
sort -R input_file | split -l $m output_prefix
```

This will make two files, one with `m` lines and one with `N-m` lines, named `output_prefixaa` and `output_prefixab`.
Make sure `m` is the larger file you want or you'll get several files of length `m` (and one with `N % m`).

If you want to ensure that you use the correct size, here's a little code to do that:

```
m=10 # size you want one file to be
N=$(wc -l input_file)
m=$(( m > N/2 ? m : N - m ))
sort -R input_file | split -l $m output_prefix
```

Edit: It has come to my attention that some `sort` implementations don't have a `-R` flag. If you have `perl`, you can substitute `perl -e 'use List::Util qw/shuffle/; print shuffle <>;'`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `sort -R` appears to only be in some versions of sort (probably the gnu version). For other platforms I wrote a tool called 'randline' which does nothing but randomize stdin. It's at http://beesbuzz.biz/code/ for anyone who needs it. (I tend to shuffle file contents quite a lot.)

Comment: Note that `sort -R` doesn't exactly sort its input randomly: it groups identical lines. So if the input is e.g. `foo`, `foo`, `bar`, `bar` and m=2, then one file will contain both `foo`s and the other will contain both `bar`s. GNU coreutils also has `shuf`, which randomizes the input lines. Also, [you can choose the output file names by using `head` and `tail` instead of `split`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29709/randomly-draw-a-certain-number-of-lines-from-a-data-file/29747#29747).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind reordering the lines and you have GNU coreutils (i.e. on non-embedded Linux or Cygwin, not too ancient since `shuf` appeared in version 6.0), [`shuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils#shuf-invocation) (“shuffle”) reorders the lines of a file randomly. So you can shuffle the file and dispatch the first m lines into one file and the rest into another.

There's no ideal way to do that dispatch. You can't just chain `head` and `tail` because `head` would buffer ahead. You can use `split`, but you don't get any flexibility with respect to the output file names. You can use `awk`, of course:

```
<input shuf | awk -v m=$m '{ if (NR <= m) {print >"output1"} else {print} }'
```

You can use `sed`, which is obscure but possibly faster for large files.

```
<input shuf | sed -e "1,${m} w output1" -e "1,${m} d" >output2
```

Or you can use `tee` to duplicate the data, if your platform has `/dev/fd`; that's ok if m is small:

```
<input shuf | { tee /dev/fd/3 | head -n $m >output1; } 3>&1 | tail -n +$(($m+1)) >output2
```

Portably, you can use awk to dispatch each line in turn. Note that awk is not very good at initializing its random number generator; the randomness is not only definitely not suitable for cryptography, but not even very good for numerical simulations. The seed will be the same for all awk invocations on any system withing a one-second period.

```
<input awk -v N=$(wc -l <input) -v m=3 '
    BEGIN {srand()}
    {
        if (rand() * N < m) {--m; print >"output1"} else {print >"output2"}
        --N;
    }'
```

If you need better randomness, you can do the same thing in Perl, which seeds its RNG decently.

```
<input perl -e '
    open OUT1, ">", "output1" or die $!;
    open OUT2, ">", "output2" or die $!;
    my $N = `wc -l <input`;
    my $m = $ARGV[0];
    while (<STDIN>) {
        if (rand($N) < $m) { --$m; print OUT1 $_; } else { print OUT2 $_; }
        --$N;
    }
    close OUT1 or die $!;
    close OUT2 or die $!;
' 42
```

Comment: *@Gilles:* For the `awk` example:  `-v N=$(wc -l <file) -v m=4` ...
and it only prints a *"random"* line when the random value is less than `$m`, rather than printing `$m` random lines... It seems that `perl` may be doing the same thing with *rand*, but I don't know `perl` well enough to get past a compilation error: *syntax error at -e line 7, near ") print"*

Comment: @Peter.O Thanks, that's what comes from typing in a browser and carelessly editing. I've fixed the awk and perl code.

Comment: All 3 methods working well and fast.. thanks (+1) ... I'm slowly getting my head around perl... and that's a particularly interesting and useful file split in the `shuf` example.

Comment: *A buffereing problem?*. Am I missing something? The `head` `cat` combo causes loss of data in the following second test *3-4* .... *TEST 1-2* `{ for i in {00001..10000} ;do echo $i; done; } | { head -n 5000 >out1; cat >out2; }` .. *TEST 3-4* `{ for i in {00001..10000} ;do echo $i; done; } >input; cat input | { head -n 5000 >out3; cat >out4; }` ... `wc -l` results for the outputs of *TEST 1-2* are **5000 5000** (good), but for *TEST 3-4* are **5000 4539** (not good).. The differnece varies depending on the file sizes involved... Here is a link to my [test code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/815040/)

Comment: @Peter.O Right again, thanks. Indeed, `head` reads ahead; what it reads ahead and doesn't print out is discarded. I've updated my answer with less elegant but (I'm reasonably sure) correct solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `m = 7` and `N = 21`:

```
cp ints ints.bak
for i in {1..7}
do
    rnd=$((RANDOM%(21-i)+1))
    # echo $rnd;  
    sed -n "${rnd}{p,q}" 10k.dat >> mlines 
    sed -i "${rnd}d" ints 
done
```

Note:
If you replace `7` with a variable like `$1` or `$m`, you have to use `seq`, not the `{from..to}`-notation, which doesn't do variable expansion.

It works by deleting line by line from the file, which gets shorter and shorter, so the line number, which can be removed, has to get smaller and smaller.

#### This should not be used for longer files, and many lines, since for every number, on average, the half file needs to be read for the 1st, and the whole file for the 2nd *sed* code.

Comment: He needs a file with the lines that are removed too.

Comment: I thought "including these m lines of data" should mean `including them` but the original lines as well - therefore `including`, not `consisting of`, and not using `only`, but I guess your interpretation is, what user288609 meant. I will adjust my script accordingly.

Comment: Looks good. ````

Comment: @user unknown: You have the `+1` in the wrong place. It should be `rnd=$((RANDOM%(N-i)+1))` where N=21 in your example.. It currently causes `sed` to crash when `rnd` is evaluated to `0`. .. Also, it doesn't scale very well with all that file re-writing. eg *123 seconds* to extract 5,000 random lines from a 10,000 line file **vs.** *0.03 seconds* for a more direct method...

Comment: @Peter.O: You're right (corrected) and you're right.